# o android notification sound is not playing

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

This is my code for making notification and notification is showing but not playing sound please help me to identify mistakes in my code and do we need any permission to play sound,vibrate for notification?

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String id = "my_channel_01";
            CharSequence name = "oreiomilla";
            String description ="i love me";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH; 
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance); 
            mChannel.setDescription(description); 
            mChannel.enableLights(true); 
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel .setSound(alarmSound,attributes);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400}); 
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel); 
            int notifyID = 1; 
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("New Message")
                    .setContentText("You've received new messages. "+ct)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)   .setTicker("Showing button notification") //
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert, "Visit", pIntent) // accept notification button
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email, "ignore", pIntent)
                    .build();
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
```

Comment: for Android O use notification Channal   https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.app.NotificationChannel&method=setSound @Midhilaj

Comment: `int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;` change to `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`

Comment: Please don't abuse the system by adding nonsense to the end of your post

Comment: Then what shoud i do to post my question?

Comment: Add more actual details, and format any text as text, and not code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this it will work for you.**

```
private void BigTextNotificationForDays(Context context, String Message, String Author) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            //To set large icon in notification
            //  Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.big_image);

            //Assign inbox style notification
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigText.bigText(Message);
            bigText.setBigContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
            bigText.setSummaryText(Author);
            //build notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,createNotificationChannel(context))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(Message)
                    .setStyle(bigText)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            //.setOngoing(true);

            // Gets an instance of the LocalNotificationManager service
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //to post your notification to the notification bar
            mNotificationManager.notify(3730, mBuilder.build()); // (int) System.currentTimeMillis() set instead of id. if at a time more notification require
        }


public static String createNotificationChannel(Context context) {

        // NotificationChannels are required for Notifications on O (API 26) and above.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // The id of the channel.
            String channelId = "Channel_id";

            // The user-visible name of the channel.
            CharSequence channelName = "Application_name";
            // The user-visible description of the channel.
            String channelDescription = "Application_name Alert";
            int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            boolean channelEnableVibrate = true;
//            int channelLockscreenVisibility = Notification.;

            // Initializes NotificationChannel.
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(channelEnableVibrate);
//            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(channelLockscreenVisibility);

            // Adds NotificationChannel to system. Attempting to create an existing notification
            // channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to perform the
            // below sequence.
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            return channelId;
        } else {
            // Returns null for pre-O (26) devices.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a sound to notifications in Oreo, you must set sound on NotificationChannel and not on Notification Builder itself. You can do this as follows

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_mp3);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
            "YOUR CHANNEL NAME",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
                context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        mChannel.setDescription(msg);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setSound(sound, attributes); // This is IMPORTANT


        if (mNotificationManager != null)
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
```

Comment: you need to attach this channel to your notification builder